# Error: Failed to build iOS app in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am not sure what happened to my project, but suddenly it is showing out errors like:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    warning: Capabilities for Runner may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID.
```

Does anyone know what causes this error? and how to resolve it?

Comment: did you build for a real device or for an emulator?

Comment: @Marc: its an emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue where I added a new dependency, and I removed as it doesn't require now. But still, in my local file changes those generated files are there. So I just removed those files and now everything runs fine.

Below files I removed it:

```
Removing project/ios/Frameworks/
Removing project/android/app/src/main/gen/
Removing project/android/app/src/profile/gen/
Removing project/asset/
Removing project/ios/Frameworks/
Removing project/ios/Frameworks/
Removing project/ios/Podfile
Removing project/ios/Podfile.lock
```